# Replacing ViewController on iPhone rotation

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, rotation

My App only has a portrait driven GUI, but there's a only section that needs to be rotated.
When the device is being rotated I want to dismiss the current View(Controller?) and replace it with a totally different looking one.
How can I do? Any example code?

Comment: So you want to load a new viewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply have 2 Different Views in the same UIViewController in the .xib file and switch between them when needed.

Let's say you have Two views in the UIViewController:

- ViewPortrait
- ViewLandscape

```
 -(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
   switch (toInterfaceOrientation)
   {
      case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
      case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
          self.view = self.ViewPortrait;   
          break;

      case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
      case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
          self.view = self.ViewLandscape;           
          break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)didRotate
{
 //Create your new view controller here if it doesn't exist.
 //Push or present the view controller
}
```